# Flask - Query route and object creation

Tags: flask

I am quite new to Flask and not sure what would be the proper way to handle that. I am working on a Flask app with a lot of view that retrieves data from `MongoDB`. I decided to build my own pagination class so I am able to modify the pagination structure based on my view.

I decided to import the `Pagination` class in one of my views where I am displaying all the customers in a table. The issue I have is my route `/clients` is handling every `GET` requests without query parameters (`http://127.0.0.1:5000/clients`) or with query parameters (`http://127.0.0.1:5000/clients?page=3`). My pagination object need to know the total number of items in order to be created `number_of_items`.

Therefore, overtime I am calling the `/client` route, I am creating a new `Pagination` object which is not my purpose as I just want to initialize the object on the first time the user reaches `/clients` and after that I will use my `increase(quantity)` and `decrease(quantity)` methods from the Pagination object to change page.

Do you have any idea on where should I avoid to create a Pagination object whenever I am changing page and instead calling methods from the Pagination object (increase and decrease page number)?

**customers/views.py**

```
@customers.route('/clients', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def clients():
    """ Client customers list overview page """
    page = request.args.get(key='page', default=0)
    collection = mongo.db[customers_production]
    number_of_items = collection.count()
    
    # just want to create that object once
    client_pagination = Pagination(number_of_items, ITEMS_PER_PAGE, 3)
    items_to_skip = client_pagination.number_of_previous_items()
    cursor = collection.find().skip(items_to_skip).limit(ITEMS_PER_PAGE)
    customers = cursor.sort("Last Name", pymongo.ASCENDING)
    page_data = client_pagination.dict()
    return render_template("clients.html", customers=customers, pagination=page_data)
```

**pagination.py**

```
class Pagination():
    def __init__(self, total_items, items_per_page, page_range):
        self.total_items = total_items  # total number of article to display in total
        self.items_per_page = items_per_page  # maximum number of article per page
        self.page_range = page_range  # number of previous and next pages to display
        self.current_page = 0
        self.number_of_pages = math.ceil(
            self.total_items / self.items_per_page)

        # if the current_page is 7 and page_range is 3 then self.following will be [8, 9, 10] and self.previous [4, 5 ,6]
        self.following = list(
            range(self.current_page + 1, self.current_page + self.page_range + 1))

        # empty because by default the current page is 0 so no previous
        self.previous = list()

    def increase(self, quantity):
        if self.current_page + quantity > self.number_of_pages:
            raise ValueError(
                f'The maximum number of pages is {self.number_of_pages}')
        else:
            self.current_page += quantity
            self.following = list()
            self.previous = list()
            for i in range(1, self.page_range + 1):
                new_following_page_number = i + self.current_page
                new_previous_page_number = self.current_page - i
                self.previous.insert(i, new_previous_page_number)
                if new_following_page_number < self.number_of_pages:
                    self.following.insert(i, new_following_page_number)

    def decrease(self, quantity):
        if self.current_page - quantity < self.number_of_pages:
            raise ValueError(f'The mimimum number of pages is 0')
        else:
            self.current_page -= quantity
            self.following = list()
            self.previous = list()
            for i in range(1, self.page_range + 1):
                new_following_page_number = i + self.current_page
                new_previous_page_number = self.current_page - i
                self.following.insert(i, new_following_page_number)
                if new_previous_page_number > self.number_of_pages:
                    self.previous.insert(i, new_previous_page_number)
       
       
    def number_of_previous_items(self):
        """ Sum of all items in all previous pages not including the current page """
        if self.current_page == 0:
            return 0
        return self.items_per_page * self.current_page

    # method call to display elements on the HTML page
    def dict(self):
        return {
            "current_page": self.current_page,
            "next_pages": self.following,
            "previous_pages": self.previous,
            "number_of_pages": self.number_of_pages
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. maybe my post was confusing but it is not about when she is coming back to that route, it's whenever she change the page of the same route. In that case, the total number of items will still be the same end the number of item per page as well

Comment: Unless Bob is adding clients at the same time. And how do you know she is "changing the page" of the same route? To find out will be a lot of bother for you for a very small gain. Getting the page is easy. Skip = page-nr * page-size (ignore if 0) and limit, well, you already have that.